# Java 8 String Comparison

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have two list of strings.
I want to check if any string from one list is available in another list.
Have used below approach which fails.

Please let me know a better approach

```
List<String> mylist = Arrays.asList(stringArray1);
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(stringArray2);

return mylist.stream().anyMatch(t->items.stream().anyMatch(t::contains));
```

Comment: `retainAll` may be?

Comment: what do you want to obtain btw? All the entries that are common?

Comment: @Eugene I want a boolean value if the any one value is available in another list

Comment: in this case, `myList.stream().anyMatch(items::contains)` should do the job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find if any element in `mylist` exists in `items`, you can first turn `items` into a `Set`:

```
Set<String> setOfItems = new HashSet<>(items);
```

Then, you can simply iterative over `mylist` and check if any element is contained in `setOfItems`.

```
mylist.stream().anyMatch(setOfItems::contains);
```

This brought your `O(n * k)` problem down to `O(n + k)` where `n` and `k` are the sizes of `mylist` and `items`, respectively.

Comment: G: Your a Rockstar, Thank you

Comment: You still can use a one-liner, `mylist.stream().anyMatch(new HashSet<>(items)::contains);`. Since this optimization only pays off for larger collections, it’s even possible to use a threshold, e.g. `static final int HASH_THRESHOLD = 30; … mylist.stream().anyMatch((items.size() < HASH_THRESHOLD? items: new HashSet<>(items))::contains);`